# Where are the easter eggs located in Monaco?

Tags: monaco

I came accross two or maybe three of the game's easter egg, playing the Mole and digging in some maps' regions.

[image: Easter egg in the Casino]

Are there others? Are there other ways to find easter eggs than digging? **Where are they located?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are the lists of all the text easter eggs I can find by digging as the Mole in the standard levels.  As of Dec. 14, 2013, almost all of these can be found by browsing though the [Steam Community Screenshots](http://steamcommunity.com/app/113020/screenshots/]) (exceptions start with an asterisk).

**Addendum**: They just released the Enhanced levels on December 15th.  I have yet to check how many of these easter eggs are still intact.  Will post when I do.

Locksmith's Story, Hijack at the Hairpin, Shoreline:

- north of boat: "You're going the wrong way!"
- northeast of previous message: "Why are you digging all the way over here?"
- north of Mole message: "Dude, the boat's not over here!"
- north of Mole: "You are nowhere near the boat my friend!"
- northeast of previous message: "Stop digging this way, there's nothing over here!"

Locksmith's Story, The Lebanese Embassy, Main Office:

- southwest of level: "OMG! What are you doing?"

Locksmith's Story, Centre Hospitalier, Helicopter Landing Pad:

- *northeast of level: "Umm, you're supposed to be rescuing The Hacker..."
- northwest of level: "What is it with you and property damage?"
- west of level: "Now you're just smashing stuff for no reason..."
- south of Hacker's skylight: "What kind of person wrecks a hospital?!?!"

Locksmith's Story, Musee Oceanographique, Top Secret Storage:

- east of level: "Nguyen, remember to put an easter egg here."

Locksmith's Story, Quartier Diamant, Underground:

- northwest of level: "Nguyen, put the secret unlock here before launch!"

Locksmith's Story, Place du Palais, Street Level:

- southeast of level: "Ain't nothing here."

Locksmith's Story, Place du Palais, Second Floor:

- south of level: "Nope! Nothing."

Locksmith's Story, Casino De Monte Carlo, VIP Poker Game:

- south of poker game: "Nguyen, put something here or you're fired!"

Pickpocket's Story, One Last Job, VIP Helipad:

- west of helicopter: "Nguyen, there is a lot of empty space here."
- south of previous message: "Use this are to create a challenge"
- south of previous message: "that will unlock the secret 9th class."
- south of previous message: "OR ELSE YOU'RE FIRED!"
- south of previous message: "I MEAN IT!"

Pickpocket's Story, Identity, Maximum Security:

- *southwest of map, west of C4: ":)"

The credits have some extra lines:

"Monaco is an online multiplayer game. You may encounter some people online that are difficult to describe as anything but nut-punchers. Please treat others online the way you would like to be treated in person. Even the nut-punchers."

"Dear Thieves, I hope you've enjoyed stealing stuff, you criminal bastards. Now go do something nice for someone. Hug someone, go outside, I don't care. Love, @andyschatz"

Answer (score 0):

If u go up to the toilet, you will start using it, unless you are the redhead, and if you do this long enough, the toilet will flush when you stop.

Answer (score -1):

There are lots of other easter eggs. Other than the occasional easter egg, there is no other way to find them other then by digging.

Simply by browsing through Monaco's [steam community](http://steamcommunity.com/app/113020/screenshots/) screenshots section, you can find screenshots of other esater eggs, but there is no list of them at this moment.

Comment: *"but there is no list of them at this moment"* - Well that's the purpose of this question :)

Comment: Well I gotta get busy then.